Problems Installing .deb Version of Steam
When I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS I unfortunately installed the SNAP version of Steam, which caused problems with certain applications not working in Steam.  After reading some articles (iirc from Steam support), I found they said the Snap version in the Ubuntu "App Center" causes the problems I was having with the game I was trying to run. The articles instructed me to install the .deb version of Steam.
Since the .deb Steam is not available to install through the Ubuntu "App Center," I've been trying to learn to do this in the terminal (grr....).
While trying to install Steam by means of the terminal (applying the command sudo apt install steam-installer), I get this message in the terminal, & the Steam install does not proceed:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam-installer : Depends: steam-libs-i386 (= 1:1.0.0.79~ds-2) but it is not >installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Prior to doing this, I also applied terminal commands sudo apt update, & sudo apt upgrade.
Someone else suggested applying the following terminal commands, which I did:

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update

Then I tried the Steam install terminal command again, and got the following message in the terminal:

32-bit Nvidia driver (nvidia-driver-libs:i386) required
This computer appears to be using the Nvidia binary graphics driver (the nvidia-driver package).
Steam is a 32-bit program, so running it on this computer requires the 32-bit versions of the Nvidia libraries, even if all the games you run via Steam are 64-bit. Please install the nvidia-driver-libs:i386 package.
For full functionality (including Vulkan), also install the libraries listed as Recommends in the nvidia-driver-libs:i386 package.
If you are using a legacy version of the Nvidia driver such as nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver, please install the corresponding 32-bit legacy package, for example nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver-libs:i386.

I need to get the .deb version of Steam running on this PC to solve a problem I was having with the Snap version not working with a game I wanted to play on Steam.
Someone else said to just install the Steam flatpack or something but I feel like I want to get Steam running from the .deb version because iirc that's what Steam told me to do to fix my initial issues.
System specs:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
RAM: 32GB
SSD:  1TB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070
OS type: 64 bit
Gnome version: 46
Windowing system: X11
Kernel version: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic
